WSO2 api manager behind nginx with SSL termination
I have an WSO2am behind nginx, I've follow all steps of this doc https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/configuring-the-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/
this my nginx.conf
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my-apimng.example.com;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com-key.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_read_timeout 5m;
        proxy_send_timeout 5m;
        proxy_pass  https://api-manager:9443/;
    }
}

When I go to https://my-apimng.example.com/admin will redirect to https://my-apimng.example.com/admin/services/auth/login and received this error in browser: The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in the data transmission was detected. Into response header have location with this content:
https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=3wb_u0QYaZc6LKbMUgdR85BD7Foa&scope=apim:admin apim:admin_alert_manage apim:admin_application_view apim:admin_operations apim:admin_settings apim:admin_tier_manage apim:admin_tier_view apim:api_category apim:api_import_export apim:api_product_import_export apim:api_provider_change apim:api_workflow_approve apim:api_workflow_view apim:app_import_export apim:app_owner_change apim:bl_manage apim:bl_view apim:bot_data apim:environment_manage apim:environment_read apim:keymanagers_manage apim:mediation_policy_create apim:mediation_policy_view apim:monetization_usage_publish apim:policies_import_export apim:role_manage apim:scope_manage apim:tenantInfo apim:tenant_theme_manage apim:tier_manage apim:tier_view openid&state=%2F&redirect_uri=https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/admin/services/auth/callback/login
where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx are (probably) last two IP of trace, last IP is the nginx. Someone can help me?
Thanks
UPDATE
I've found this guide -> https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-invalid-callback-error/ and have modified callback URL with my domain but not have resolved

Step 4.2 in this guide: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/configuring-the-proxy-server-and-the-load-balancer/#step-4-configure-the-dynamic-callback-origin
Default value of "forwardedHeader" is "X-Forwarded-For", need change to "X-Forwarded-Host"
